# ElasticSearch and Couchdb view

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

New to the whole ElasticSearch and couchDB setup. Just got a river going from ES to a db I have in couchDB. If I have a view in a db is there a way to just index that view? For example I have a db named "Movies" and a view called "Action" and another called "byActor".

I was thinking that I could do an index and point it to that, like below, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
{
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "db" : "Movies",
        "filter" : null
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "Action",
        "bulk_size" : "100",
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }
}
```

I think I may not understand what index is exactly because when I run `http://localhost:9200/Movies/Action/_search?pretty=true` nothing is returned.

**Edit:** In looking around more it's seeming like this isn't the way to do this. Index just seems to be the way ES indexes? Anyways, I'm reading that mapping might accomplish this. Is that true?

Comment: Can you tell us what path you PUT this document to?

Comment: You also have syntax errors in your JSON document. You have 4 closing braces and only 2 opening braces. See https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/blob/master/README.md for an example of the structure the river document should have.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the brackets. Got that taken care of. In regards to the path: curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_river/testRiver/_meta -d @videoTest.txt. From what I understand the river is just an ES thing, not a couchdb thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing views is not yet in CouchDb River. See this [pull request](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/pull/24).

Comment: Well shucks. So i'm guessing filters are the way to accomplish this?